# After rendering, why can't I find the render on the hard drive?

Tags: rendering

After rendering my render image, I cannot find my file in File Explorer, I set the output like this:

[image]

But I still can't find my image after rendering at *C:\Users\User\Documents\Blender stuff*.

Comment: if you clicked render image, it wont automatically be placed in that directory. it works only for animation. If you got to rendering tab, you can find your render result. click image > save as...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39022/how-to-save-render **and** https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139774/why-is-my-rendered-my-image-not-being-saved-as-a-file

Answer (score 1):

As stated by other on this page, when you press <kbd>F12</kbd>, or use "Render Image", the rendered image is not saved automatically.

Only when you use "Render Animation", the images are saved in the path specified in the output section.

To save an image manually, go to the **Image editor** window and use "**Save Image As**" (Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

To save an image automatically every time, you can add a file output node in the compositor.

Alternatively, you can set the "Frame Start" and "End Frame" to 1 and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (or "Render Animation") to render. Then the image will be saved to the path specified on the "Output" settings.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> after any render.
As state by Shantanu, blender doesn't save automatically render images